# How do I delete everything not matching the HH:MM pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

So i have a csv file with all times but some other foreign text got in:

```
07:56 p.m. 
le: iTune
ap: Apple   
05:45 a.m.         
01:23 p.m.     
10:yh      
12:20 p.m.      
gh:50
ke: The n
```

is there a command with `sed` which I can filter out all the lines that do not have the HH:MM format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `sed` is possible with inline editing flag:

```
sed -i.bak -n '/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/p' file

cat file
07:56 p.m. 
05:45 a.m.         
01:23 p.m.     
12:20 p.m.
```

You can also use `grep`:

```
grep '^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' file
07:56 p.m. 
05:45 a.m.         
01:23 p.m.     
12:20 p.m.
```

Comment: WOW the response time was awesome! Thanks both worked well, just curious though which would run faster because I have a csv file of around 10000 of these time entries..would `grep` or `sed` be faster?

Comment: Better use sed as that saves 1 step of saving output in a different file but do take a backup first :)

Comment: alright thanks so much! I love this community! everyone helps each other. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: may i suggest /^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/p' or [0-1][0-9] if a.m and p.m are used

Answer (score 1):

Same with `awk`

```
awk '/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/' file
07:56 p.m.
05:45 a.m.
01:23 p.m.
12:20 p.m.
```